# How do you get a ship?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Supposedly you can get your own spaceship, but how do I go about doing that?
I am level 13, and have left the beginner area ages ago.

I have checked the hangar, at republic fleet, but it just said there was no ship for me there, and wouldn't let me enter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After completing the last class quest (about level 16) on your second planet you will receive your ship.

You will recive a space ship after the following quest:

**Planet: Dromund Kaas**

- Imperial Agent - [Cleaning Up the Mess](http://www.swtor-spy.com/quests/cleaning-up-the-mess/976/)
- Sith Inquisitor – [In The Halls Of Traitors](http://www.swtor-spy.com/quests/in-the-halls-of-traitors/926/)
- Sith Warrior – [Leaving Dromund Kaas](http://www.swtor-spy.com/quests/leaving-dromund-kaas/917/)
- Bounty Hunter – [Joy Ride](http://www.swtor-spy.com/quests/joy-ride/860/)

**Planet: Coruscant**

- Jedi Consular - [Ancient Secrets](http://www.swtor-spy.com/quests/ancient-secrets/786/)
- Trooper – [Assault On The Works](http://www.swtor-spy.com/quests/assault-on-the-works/758/)
- Smuggler – [Race the Devil](http://www.swtor-spy.com/quests/race-the-devil/747/)
- Jedi Knight – [Race to the Ruins](http://www.swtor-spy.com/quests/race-to-the-ruins/816/)

The ship you receive depends on your class:

Jedi Knight & Jedi Consular – [Corellian Defender](http://www.swtor.com/info/holonet/starships/defender)

Smuggler – [Corellian XS Stock Light Freighter](http://www.swtor.com/info/holonet/starships/xs-freighter)

Trooper – [Rendili Hyperworks BT-7 Thunderclap](http://www.swtor.com/info/holonet/starships/bt-7-thunderclap)

Sith Warror & Sith Inquisitor – [Fury-Class Imperial Interceptor](http://www.swtor.com/info/holonet/starships/fury)

Imperial Agent – [X-70b-Phantom Prototype](http://www.swtor.com/info/holonet/starships/x-70b-phantom)

Bounty Hunter – [D5-Mantis](http://www.swtor.com/info/holonet/starships/d5-mantis)

[Source](http://www.swtor-spy.com/guides/how-to-get-and-upgrade-your-starship-in-swtor/190/) and [official site](http://www.swtor.com/info/holonet/starships)

Answer (score 3):

You get your ship when your class story arc takes you off the second planet (Dromund Kass or Coruscant). It's not directly related to your level, but I think you should be usually around level 15 at that point.